# Settings for Javascript window print

Tags: javascript, pdf

I would like to print my webpage as an pdf with the `window.print()`. Right now I just get the dialog box up as default. I was wondering if I could make it select print to pdf and then proceed by it self.

[image]

I have tried classes like dompdf etc., but this print to pdf is really what I need here. So if it is possible to set some default printing settings and maybe make it automatically, then let me know.

Comment: no, not really. printing from browsers has always been crap, and you have essentially ZERO control over how/where the browser will choose to print. And allowing a webpage to trigger a complete print job on its own would be a masssive security problem. consider your average script kiddy all excited over `<script>while(1) { window.print(override_everything_and_force_print_job); }</script>`. say goodbye to your paper/toner/ink budget.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment no you cannot do this. Also not sure if you have custom print `button` or you are using `Ctrl+P` shortcut.

In cases you may see a PDF is opened in a new tab and you can download from there.

Otherwise in operations like bank account summary download , generally handled by a kind of `form submit` , and the pdf is created by controller/service layer by using PDF Generator like `iText`.

[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118635/what-is-the-best-pdf-open-source-library-for-java) is a link for information on PDF open source library.